# Issues with custom age verification WordPress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've been working with my boss on creating this age verification plugin for one of our clients. It needs to automatically populate the country based on IP address, which I've mostly worked out... The only thing stopping me from pushing this live is the fact that the script at the top of the document isn't cooperating with the existing code. It throws a connection error warning. I think if I wrote all of this myself, I'd have an easier time getting things sorted, but my boss wrote almost all of the PHP. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[Here](https://test-cask88-store.pantheonsite.io/) is a link to the live site and my code below.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Cask 88 Age Verify Plugin
Description: Plugin to verify age and capture email from site visitors
*/
?>

<script>
    $.countryLocalizeSelect = jQuery.fn.countryLocalizeSelect = function (authKey) {
    var $elems = this;

    var country = null;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'https://ipfind.co/me?auth=' + authKey,
        success: function(data){
            if (data.country){
                $elems.each(function(){
                    var $el = $(this);
                    $el.val(data.country);
                });
            }           
        },
    }); 
    return this;
};

$('#ag-region').countryLocalizeSelect("925efaf7-5b1a-4955-90b2-3237c496d5d9");
</script>

<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}


function c88_age_head(){
    
    
}

function c88_age_body(){


    print 'HELLO!';
    
    $code = <<< EOT

    <center>
        <div>Test!</div>
        <div class="verify_overlay">
            
            <div>
                <div class="steps step1">
                    <div class="error" style="display:none;color:#721c24;background-color:#f8d7da;border:1px solid #f5c6cb;padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;border-radius: 0.25rem;"><div class="error_msg"></div></div>
                    <img id="verify-logo" src="https://cask88.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Asset-1@300x.png">

                    <div id="verify-text">
                    <div class="verify" style="color: #B49861;">PLEASE VERIFY YOUR AGE AND LOCATION TO CONTINUE</div><br>
                    <div id = "date-range">
                
                    <input type="text" id="ag-month" placeholder="MM" /> <input id="ag-day" type="text" placeholder="DD" /> <input type="text" id="ag-year" placeholder="YYYY"> <br />
                        </div>

                        <select id="ag-region" class="dbip-auto-select-country" name="ag-region" class="age-gate-select" required="">
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                <option value="China">China</option>
                <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
                <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
                <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
                <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
                <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
                <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
                <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
                <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
                <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
                <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
                <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
                <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
                <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                    </select> </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="button enter-site">Enter Site</a>
                    </div>
                    

                </div>
                <div class="steps step2">
                    <div class="error" style="display:none;color:#721c24;background-color:#f8d7da;border:1px solid #f5c6cb;padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;border-radius: 0.25rem;"><div class="error_msg"></div></div>
                    <img id="verify-logo" src="https://cask88.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Asset-1@300x.png">
                    <div id= "step2_text">
                    <div class= "step2_text1"style= "color: #B49861; margin-top:5% !important; margin-bottom: 1%;">Subscribe To Cask 88 Newsletter</div><br>
                    <div class="step2_text2" style="color: #B49861"; margin-bottom: 2em;>Want to find out first about new cask offerings and whisky releases? Signup for the Cask 88 newsletter to get weekly updates.</div>
                    
                    Your Email Address: <br />
                    <input type="text" id="ag-email" style="width: 75%; background-color: transparent; color: #B49861;" placeholder="your@email.com" /><br /><br />
                    
                    <a href="#" class="button email-signup">Sign Up</a> or, &nbsp <a href="#" class="email-cancel">Skip</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="steps loading">
                    <img id="age-gif" src="https://dev-cask88-store.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/age-gif.gif"/>
            
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div>


        <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('body,html').css('overflow','hidden');
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.verify_overlay').animate({top:'0%'},1000);
            },1000);
            
            $('.enter-site').bind('click',function(e){
                $('.steps').hide();
                $('.steps.loading').show();
                $('.steps.step1 .error').hide();
                
                var data = {};
                data['action'] = 'cask88-verify-age';
                data['location'] = $('#ag-region').val();
                data['month'] = $('#ag-month').val();
                data['day'] = $('#ag-day').val();
                data['year'] = $('#ag-year').val();
                
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:data,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success:function(obj){
                        if(obj.success == true){
                            if(obj.valid == true){
                                $('.steps').hide();
                                $('.steps.step2').show();
                            
                                $('.steps.step2 .error').hide();
                            } else {
                                window.location = obj.redirect;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $('.steps').hide();
                            $('.steps.step1').show();
                            $('.steps.step1 .error').show();
                            $('.steps.step1 .error_msg').html(obj.error||'Error! Please try again!');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        $('.steps').hide();
                        $('.steps.step1').show();
                        $('.steps.step1 .error').show();
                        $('.steps.step1 .error_msg').html('Connection Error! Please try again!');
                    }
                });
                
                return false;
            });
            
            
            $('.email-signup').bind('click',function(e){
                $('.steps').hide();
                $('.steps.loading').show();
                $('.steps.step2 .error').hide();
                
                var data = {};
                data['action'] = 'cask88-verify-email';
                data['email'] = $('#ag-email').val();
                
                
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:data,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success:function(obj){
                        if(obj.success == true){
                            $('.verify_overlay').animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
                        } else {
                            $('.steps').hide();
                            $('.steps.step2').show();
                            $('.steps.step2 .error').show();
                            $('.steps.step2 .error_msg').html(obj.error||'Connection Error! Please try again!');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        $('.steps').hide();
                        $('.steps.step2').show();
                        $('.steps.step2 .error').show();
                        $('.steps.step2 .error_msg').html('Connection Error! Please try again!');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
            
            
            $('.email-cancel').bind('click',function(e){
                $('.verify_overlay').animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
                return false;
            });
            
            
        });
        </script>
EOT;
    
    print $code;
    //return $code;
}


add_action('wp_head', 'c88_age_head');


add_action('wp_footer','c88_age_body');



add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cask88-verify-age', 'cask88_verify_age');
add_action('wp_ajax_cask88-verify-age', 'cask88_verify_age');

function cask88_verify_age(){
    $location = $_REQUEST['location'];
    $month = $_REQUEST['month'];
    $day = $_REQUEST['day'];
    $year = $_REQUEST['year'];
    
    if(!$month OR !$day OR !$year OR !$location){
        
        print json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'You must enter your birth date and location.'));
        die();
    }
    
    if($location == 'United States'){
        $age = 21;
    } else {
        $age = 18;
    }
    
    $time = strtotime("-" . $age . " year", time());
    $check_year = date("Y", $time);
    $check_month = date("m", $time);
    $check_day = date("d", $time);
   
    if($year < $check_year){
        print json_encode(array('success' => true, 'valid' => true));
    } else if($year == $check_year AND $month>$check_month){
        print json_encode(array('success' => true, 'valid' => true));
    } else if($year == $check_year AND $month==$check_month AND $day>=$check_day){
        print json_encode(array('success' => true, 'valid' => true));
    } else {
        print json_encode(array('success' => true, 'valid' => false, 'redirect' => 'https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/'));
    }
   
   
    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cask88-verify-email', 'cask88_verify_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_cask88-verify-email', 'cask88_verify_email');

function cask88_verify_email(){
    global $wpdb;
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $nowdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    
    if($email){
        $wpdb->insert('wp_cask88_age_emails',array('email' => $email,'date' => $nowdate));
    }
    
    print json_encode(array('success' => true));
   
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain this more? What specifically is the connection error warning saying? Do you know if it's not working due to a PHP issue or a JS issue? Can you edit your question to only show the _rendered_ HTML/JS (i.e. the output of PHP)? This goes along with creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because pasting all of your code and asking for help is much more complicated than providing a minimal example of it not working, which will be much easier to debug.

Comment: And most people (especially other developers) don't want to or don't trust clicking on a random link to see the issue - this question should be as complete as possible without needing to view another site. If it's a PHP issue, edit your question and copy/paste the text of the actual error here. If it's a JS issue, you should be able to replicate it here using [a code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet).